# Disallowing interaction with background form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

On my application's first run, two forms open. The topmost form needs to take priority, and disallow any interaction with the form in the background. I have tried `ShowDialog()` as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970006/two-forms-on-startup-with-background-form-inaccessible-until-button-is-pressed-o), however this hides the form in the background which I do not wish to do. Is there a method of accomplishing this?

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!fileexists(@"c:\Management Tools\Absence Tracker\bin\data\tbase.skf"))
            { firstrunactions(); }
        }
void firstrunactions()
        {
            //open the get-started form and invite user to populate serialisable objects
            firstrun frwindow = new firstrun();
            frwindow.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: ShowDialog() does not "hide" a form.  Post code.  And use the Enabled property to disable interaction.

Comment: It doesn't hide the form as such, however using it here causes my primary form not to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `.ShowDialog()` the execution of the containing method is paused until you close the newly opened window. So make sure to do everthing else *before* you call `.ShowDialog()`. Otherwise your program gets stuck in this method. If you are calling `.ShowDialog()` before the background window is shown will cause problems.
But using `.ShowDialog()` here is totally correct and has the right functionality.

Example how ***not*** to do it (causes the same behavior like in your problem):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this is the wrong place for showing a child window because it "hides" its parent
        Form frwindow = new Form();
        frwindow.ShowDialog(this);
    }
```

The magical place where it works:

```
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frwindow = new Form();
        frwindow.ShowDialog(this);
    }
```

Edit: In your case it is enough moving `if(!fileexistst...)` into the `Form1_Shown()`-event.

Comment: Did it work? Are you still facing this problem? Do you have any other questions? Feel free to ask! :)

Comment: Hello, this is perfect! And this is a really good explanation too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with frwindow.ShowDialog(this);
Or instead "this" pass the other form as parameter.
Also move this part `if (!fileexists(@"c:\Management Tools\Absence Tracker\bin\data\tbase.skf"))
            { firstrunactions(); }
        }`
in OnLoad override.